# Passing values between widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am trying to achieve a sign-up screen that is splinted between 7 screens, each screen should take single input.

I tried passing around arguments to my page route, but I feel not good about that,  since I don't need it until the last screen where I make a server request.
I  don't know how should I do that.

I tried with the provider, but I could not achieve a code with no errors I tried to create an instance of a provider class witch tack nullable parameters and then call it in the widget that should tack input and set the values to it, but I faced many errors.

Any advice.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class UserSignUpModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final String? fName;
  final String? lName;
  final String? gender;

  UserSignUpModel(
      {
      this.fName,
      this.lName,
      this.gender,
      });
  var user = new UserSignUpModel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make this field `static` and then assign the values one by one to this `UserSignUpModel`. Like in the first page you can only take name and directly assign it to `UserSignUpModel.name`.
Your UserSignUpModel would look like bellow

```
class UserSignUpModel {
  static String? fName;
  static String? lName;
  static String? gender;
}
```

Comment: You could use Bloc pattern or another state management approach. https://bloclibrary.dev/#/.

Comment: Actually I haven't tried any of these but I will surely try for my next project.

Answer (score 0):

it was very easy to do

```
class UserSignUpModel with ChangeNotifier {
  String? fName;
  String? lName;
  String? gender;
  String? userLookingfor;
  String? userType;
  String? userTagLine;
  String? userEmail;
  String? userPhoneCode;
  String? userEmailCode;
  String? userPassword;
  String? age;
  void createUserName(String valFNmae, String valLname) {
    fName = valFNmae;
    lName = valLname;
  }
```

and in the other widget

```
final helper = Provider.of<UserSignUpModel>(context, listen: false);
    helper.createUserName(
        _firstNameController.value.text, _lastNameController.value.text);
```